# Display N number of records from a PDO MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

I'm trying to figure out how to only display the 1st 10 records (1-10) or the 2nd 10 records (11-20), or etc...

The code below does a great job of pulling all records, but I can't figure out how to modify it to only show N number of records. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    include 'database.php';       
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM trail101 ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        //my code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `limit` to define the offset and number of records you want. To get the first 10 use:

```
SELECT * FROM trail101 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

to get the next 10:

```
LIMIT 10, 10
```